# Assigning to a variable if string is null

Tags: java, null

I have a code that sets the instance variables name, although if the user enters null the name should appear as "Unknown" 
I am unable to think of how to do this, please check out my code and help me with how I am going about it wrong. Thanks!

My code:

```
  if (name.equals(null))
    {
        this.name = name;
        name="Unknown";
    }
    else
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
```

Comment: How would they enter `null`? Do you mean the `String` value `"null"`? If you are checking reference equality, use `==`.

Comment: No! `"null"` does not == `null`, not even close. If the user enters null, then they're entering the String, `"null"`, and that is what I guess you should check. But that has nothing to do with a null variable, which is an unassigned variable.

Comment: You code is very confusing with `this.name` and `name`.  If `name` is just a parameter why are you setting it?

Comment: Sorry if i'm not being thorough. I mean the user literally enters null. not in quotes

Comment: You are unclear on what a String represents. The user is entering "null". Period. The quotes are not entered by the user and are only used when entered in your program. If the user entered `"null"` with quotes, then the string he is then entering would be represented in your program would be `""null""`.

Comment: NULL should be compared to object instead as a String to check for NULL object. so we do use "==". .equals() is a method for String object to compare against string or character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user enters null it has to be checked with "null" String, like below. Have added few more checks.

```
if (name == null || "".equals(name.trim()) || "null".equals(name)) {
        this.name = name;
        this.name="Unknown";
} else {
        this.name=name;
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I tried the == instead of .equals() and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (name.equals("null"))
{
   name = "Unknown";
}
```

Comment: As it stands, this is considered a low-quality post.  Try adding an explanation as to why this will solve the issue.